# Getting special characters when I try to list out all filenames

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab and I fairly new to it, so please pardon my ignorance. I am trying to get the file names of all the frames in a certain folder.

```
filenames_pics = !ls {PATH}/Pictures
```

I do this to try to copy all the filenames.

The output I get when i try to print it is

```
['frame1000.png\tframe15320.png\tframe436.png  frame572.png  frame680.png',
'frame1004.png\tframe15324.png\tframe440.png  frame576.png  frame684.png',
'frame1008.png\tframe1588.png\tframe508.png  frame580.png  frame688.png',
'frame100.png\tframe1592.png\tframe512.png  frame584.png  frame692.png',
'frame1012.png\tframe16432.png\tframe516.png  frame588.png  frame696.png']
```

What is interesting is that all the first values have this '\t' in it with three frame names in it, and this is just driving me mad.

All my file names are in oder

Please help!

Comment: replace `'\t'` with space `' ' ` and split on space `' ' `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably simpler to use the built-in Python `os.listdir` function.

Here's a full example:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EKhDSUHBfzGdRPxm9gBGPfDGQ2vX5cPe

The key snippet:

```
# Python code to list the directory.
import os
pictures = os.listdir('Pictures/')
for fname in pictures:
  print (fname)
  print ('full path', os.path.join(os.getcwd(), fname))
```

Comment: Hello! thank you so much. This worked like a charm to get the filenames! :)

Comment: The output that i was trying to get was ['frame1000.png frame15320.png frame436.png frame572.png frame680.png', 'frame1004.png frame15324.png frame440.png frame576.png frame684.png', 'frame1008.png frame1588.png frame508.png frame580.png frame688.png', 'frame100.png frame1592.png frame512.png frame584.png frame692.png', 'frame1012.png frame16432.png frame516.png frame588.png frame696.png']

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace `'\t` with space to match the pattern

```
lst=['frame1000.png\tframe15320.png\tframe436.png  frame572.png  frame680.png',
'frame1004.png\tframe15324.png\tframe440.png  frame576.png  frame684.png',
'frame1008.png\tframe1588.png\tframe508.png  frame580.png  frame688.png',
'frame100.png\tframe1592.png\tframe512.png  frame584.png  frame692.png',
'frame1012.png\tframe16432.png\tframe516.png  frame588.png  frame696.png']

l=[]
import re
for i in lst:
    l.append(re.sub('\s{2,}|\t',' ',i))
print(l)
```

Output:

```
['frame1000.png frame15320.png frame436.png frame572.png frame680.png',
 'frame1004.png frame15324.png frame440.png frame576.png frame684.png',
 'frame1008.png frame1588.png frame508.png frame580.png frame688.png',
 'frame100.png frame1592.png frame512.png frame584.png frame692.png',
 'frame1012.png frame16432.png frame516.png frame588.png frame696.png']
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for the quick response.

The output that i was trying to get was 

   ['frame1000.png  frame15320.png  frame436.png  frame572.png  frame680.png',
'frame1004.png  frame15324.png  frame440.png  frame576.png  frame684.png',
'frame1008.png   frame1588.png   frame508.png  frame580.png  frame688.png',
'frame100.png  frame1592.png   frame512.png  frame584.png  frame692.png',
'frame1012.png frame16432.png  frame516.png  frame588.png  frame696.png']

Comment: @BhaskarGhosh Edited